# Finding Difference in Time with no displacement

Tags: kinematics

I have a very simple kinematics problem on my hands for my homework, I cannot ask anyone right now, and it is basically a test grade so I want to get it right AND understand it well.

> Two boats start together and race across a 60 km wide lake and back. Boat A goes across at 60 km/hr and returns at 60 km/hr. Boat B goes across at 30 km/hr, and returns at 90 km/hr. Turnaround times are negligible, the best that completes the round trip first wins>

I am supposed to determine by how much time the winner wins using kinematics. I certainly know how to figure it out by logic and by a graph of pos. vs. time, but not using kinematics. The overall displacement of both boats is 0 because they returned to the start, therefore average velocity is also 0. What would I need to do to find it using basic kinematics? (I am just in the start of the year so I have no prior experience).

Comment: There's a lot of guidance about helping with homework questions - it's essentially not helpful to do them for you. A moderator will probably intervene on this post.
However, in response to the specific "conceptual" issue you have defined in your final para, if the average velocity over each entire journey is zero, but clearly intutitively there has been movement, how might non-zero averages be calculated and used?

Comment: Kinematic equations only work with constant acceleration (or none). The round trip has a discontinuity in it. Break the journey into two parts: outbound, and return. Find the time taken for each segment for each boat. Do you have a kinematic equation for that?

Comment: I guess that would just be t = x/v when I simplify the equation I do have for that. I guess I didn't see it before, because I tried to split it up into separate back and forth, but I am not that good at Algebra so I messed up the equation. Thank you all, next time I will make a better question and only ask about the concept, not the homework, and when I only really need it.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems.](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may find that the motion becomes clearer if you draw either a displacement against time sketch graph with the gradient of such a graph equal to the velocity or a velocity against time sketch graph where the area under the graph is equal to the displacement.

[image]

You then do not really need to do any calculations to answer your question.